# PC throwing BSOD or randomly restarting

Tags: memory, power-supply, bsod, reboot

So for the past week I had 2 times BSOD or PC just randomly restarted every single time.

I ran memory diagnostic tool and it found no problems, I ran chkdsk and it also found no problems.

I think it's not PSU because yesterday it happened once and then my PC didn't restart at all until next day even tho I played games. And also my PSU is relatively new. (Around 1 year)

It shouldn't be overheating, I checked my temperatures and they are completely okay.
My system is not corrupted, after these issues I reinstalled Windows again (it's also not driver issue then).
I also disabled fast startup.

The bsod I had was "cl.dll" and "not less or equal".

Btw, it's not new PC, I have this PC for quite a long time and until now it was okay.

My PC:

- CPU: i7 860
- GPU: GT 1030
- RAM: 12 GB DDR3
- PSU: 400W
- Windows 10

What do you think is the problem? I couldn't find any solution.

Keywords from event viewer:

- 0x80000000000000
- 0x8000400000000002 (Kernel-Power)

(Also, I have one HDD on which I have Linux and is not used, but on startup I keep getting error message that the disk is in bad condition, I don't think it could be it, by just in case I want to ask: Is it possible that this HDD is causing those random restarts?)

the whole XML View:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" /> 
  <EventID>41</EventID> 
  <Version>8</Version> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <Task>63</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000400000000002</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-08-10T14:33:57.0546271Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>2095</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-6OPK6D6</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="SleepInProgress">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BootAppStatus">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="Checkpoint">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="ConnectedStandbyInProgress">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="SystemSleepTransitionsToOn">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceId">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckInfoFromEFI">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="CheckpointStatus">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceIdV2">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="LongPowerButtonPressDetected">false</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: *Is it possible that this HDD is causing those random restarts?* The best thing to do would be to remove the faulty HDD.

Comment: I removed it just now, and PC booted just fine. I will give my update tomorrow on this, just to be sure it helped. (yesterday restart happened once and then everything was okay until next day)

Answer (score -1):

Try uninstalling any updates quality or security you had installed recently.
Additionally you can disable your AV just for testing purposes.

Hope that helps.

V

Comment: That's what I tried before reinstalling, sadly it didn't change anything. PC still keeps restarting.

Comment: Did you check in the event viewer? Filter them bu error and warnings and check the restart code. You can read the BSOD error using this app: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

Comment: I just edited my post and added the keywords I got from it and also little information at the bottom.

Comment: Here are bugcheck codes I got from the app: 0x0000000a (IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL) and 0x00000139.

Comment: This might be caused if you didn't format the disk while installing. it needs to create a new Master boot record. Also post the entire XML code of the event stop code.

Comment: I did format the disk while installing. I always do.

Comment: I edited my post with the XML.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Check the processor seating -> https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/bsod-and-random-crashes-331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e/d09e8759-c0a4-483f-83bd-ad90c1ee65af

Comment: I applied new thermal paste just recently, so it should be fine. And my temperatures are also fine.

Answer (score -1):

So, the problem really caused HDD on which I had linux and was in bad condition.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1139958)

Comment: I answered what caused the issues I experienced and this may prove useful to somebody else in similar situation (I didn't remove the HDD just simply because I thought it couldn't be it).